# Laravel query Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got strange behavior when creating scope function inside model

```
class Measurement extends Model {
        public function scopeGetMeasurement($query, $user_id) {
            $measurements = $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->join('measurement_metas', 'measurements.id', '=', 'measurement_metas.measurement_id')
                ->join('units', 'measurement_metas.unit_id', '=', 'units.id');

            return $measurements;
        }
    }
```

I have 3 tables like this: 
**measurements**

[image: measurements]
**measurement_metas**

[image: measurement_metas]
**units**

[image: units]
What happen `$measurements` return `id` as `unit_id` not `measurements.id`
[image: JSON]

What I am doing wrong?

**Clarifying**:
All I want is the 'id' become = 'measurements.id' not 'units.id', but since the 'units.id' come last it appear as the 'id'.

Comment: Or add `select('measurements.*')` to your query scope.

Comment: @fubar But this will return only measurements table columns.

Comment: Correct. It wasn't clear from your question what your desired output is. But the point is, you can alias the columns you want as required.

Comment: @fubar All I want is the 'id' become = 'measurements.id' not 'units.id', but since the 'units.id' came last it appear as the 'id'.

Comment: update your question with the columns you actually want to select from all three tables

Comment: @fubar already done.

Answer (score 1):

Your query selects all columns of all joined tables (`SELECT *`), so the last `id` column (`unit`) overwrites the previous ones (`measurements`, `measurement_metas`).

You should use relationships for this kind of queries:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

For example:
User → `HasMany` → Measurement
Measurement → `HasMany` → Measurement_Meta
Measurement_Meta → `BelongsTo` → Unit

Then use eager loading to load them all at once:

```
User::find($user_id)->load('measurements.metas.unit')
```